# Why is stack rewriting my .cabal file and throwing away my edits to add a new dependency?

Tags: haskell-stack

Stack is suddenly misbehaving. I created a new project, wrote some code, needed a new dependency (containers, to get Data.Map.Strict), so I edited my project .cabal file to add the dependency and now stack is rewriting my .cabal file to throw away my edits (which makes the build fail).

What stupid simple thing have I missed?

(I committed what I had to git and started over.)

```
rm -fr Problem032
stack new Problem032
cd Problem032
stack setup
stack build
stack exec Problem032-exe
```

all works fine.  But then...

```
vi Problem032.cabal
```

to add ",containers" to the lib build-depends

```
cd src
git checkout -- Lib.hs
```

to get my old broken code back

```
cd ..
stack build
```

Results in my .cabal file getting rewritten (to lose the new dependency) and then the build fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the default stack template now uses hpack for package descriptions. You can either delete package.yaml or instead edit it.  Stack 1.6.1 which was just released, has much better behavior for this circumstance.

Comment: Doesn't help that "stack upgrade" updates ~/.local/bin, which isn't on my path, while the original curl | sh trick installed it to /usr/local/bin, but, yes, thanks, this was the help I needed.

Comment: I do believe stack will warn you that it isn't on your PATH when doing that.  However, yes, you do need to pay attention to the warning.  I suppose if the current exe location is writeable, it should do that.  I've put down a TODO note about it

Comment: It does. Sadly, many warnings these days are like lint output in the old days (and I ignored it). Ideally, it'd be configurable where it writes the output, defaulting to current behavior.

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3708 about having better upgrade behavior